# Is this code protected against SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm not so familiar with the newer PHP commands, so I wanted to check with you if the code below is protected against SQL injection?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server,$user , $password, $db_name);
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("insert into $db_table (request_date, from_city, from_country, to_city, to_country, travel_date, return_date, minus, plus, currency) 
                                        values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt1->bind_param("ssssssssss",$date,
                                $_POST['from_city'], 
                                $_POST['from_country'], 
                                $_POST['to_city'], 
                                $_POST['to_country'], 
                                $_POST['travel_date'], 
                                $_POST['return_date'], 
                                $_POST['minus'], 
                                $_POST['plus'], 
                                $_POST['currency']
                    );

$stmt1->execute();
```

Basically, the script receives post data from the form, records them into a db, and then submits them to another script to perform the actual search (on a third-party website).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, prepared statements are safe against SQL injection as they are not interpreted as part of the SQL query - you can have anything there, it won't execute a command.

That said, you may want to do a bit of validation anyway to make sure the data you are accepting makes sense. Garbage in, Garbage out. You don't want to save a date that's not valid, for instance.